# Geranium petals are drying out

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, flowers, watering, pruning

My geranium petals are drying out. They are sitting in a jute lined crate, plenty of drainage (which I need because it rains on and off in this city a lot). However, I test the soul every few days and always rewater when the soil gets dry. So I don’t think it’s under-watering…Is there another cause for this issue? There haven’t been too many hot sunny days yet this season, so I don’t think they’re sunburnt either. Thanks!

Also please let me know if it’s best to remove the dead petals at this point.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dying petals are just a sign that that particular stem with blooms on the end is almost finished, that's all - trace the stem down to where you can feel a small bump, put your finger and thumb round it, then bend the stem firmly to one side at that point and it should just come away cleanly. Your 'geranium' (it's actually a *Pelargonium*) otherwise looks healthy.